# Applescript vs. Spaces in Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, applescript, spaces

In Snow Leopard (10.6), I had an applescript that toggled iTunes between "maximised on Space 2" and "mini-player on all spaces":

```
set app_identifier to do shell script "echo 'com.apple.iTunes' | /usr/bin/perl -pe 'use encoding utf8; s/(\\w)/\\L$1/gi'"

tell application "iTunes"
    # if it's not already minimised...
    if minimized of front browser window is false then
        # switch to mini player
        set minimized of front browser window to true
        # set it to show on all spaces (the magic here is the "65544").
        set app_construct to (run script "{|" & app_identifier & "|: 65544}")
        tell application "System Events"
            tell expose preferences
                tell «class essp»
                    set spaces_bindings to get «class spcs»
                    set spaces_bindings to app_construct & spaces_bindings
                    set «class spcs» to spaces_bindings
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    else
        # switch to normal player
        set minimized of front browser window to false
        # set it to show on Space 2 (the magic here is the "2" - compare to the "65544" in the "set to all spaces" version).
        set app_construct to (run script "{|" & app_identifier & "|: 2}")
        tell application "System Events"
            tell expose preferences
                tell «class essp»
                    set spaces_bindings to get «class spcs»
                    set spaces_bindings to app_construct & spaces_bindings
                    set «class spcs» to spaces_bindings
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

That's based on scripts from http://soylentfoo.jnewland.com/articles/2007/11/22/spaces-application-assignments-and-applescript .

This doesn't work on Lion.

Does anyone know the equivalent to "assign this app to all spaces" and "assign this app to space 2" in Lion?